# Calculating flow rate of water across a water turbine

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, flow

How can I calculate the time for water flow across a Peltom turbine, given the flow rate and volume of the water at the instance before it reaches the turbine? I know time = volume/flow rate, but I want to know the effect the turbine has on time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow rate for a liquid does not change at different points in its transference. For instance if it is 10 liters per minute in a small diameter pipe and then the pipe expands into a larger diameter, it will still be 10 liters per minute in the larger pipe. The velocity of the liquid may change but not the flow rate, as you cannot have more or less liquid per minute coming out than what went in.